# How to get process id of spring cloud task triggered from Spring cloud dataflow

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

How to get process id of spring cloud task triggered from Spring cloud dataflow.
If we triggered a job from Spring cloud dataflow an execution id will be assigned for every task ,but I need to get process id of triggered job.

When we triggered spring cloud task  due to some exception it will maintain unknown status in SCDF.
we need to get the process id and kill that process.

Comment: Sounds like you running SCDF locally in prod? We don’t recommend that. Kubernetes or Cloud Foundry handle such concerns. On linux or Mac, you can use `jps`. I don’t know what the equivalent on Windows would be.